# How do I Set TreeViewItem width to the maximum space available

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, styles

I'm new to WPF and style, i want apply to TreeViewItem a style like this

[image: Style]

These are my two goals:

1. Have an alternative rows colour grey and white, and when i expand the Tree, i want the correct alternative row colour, i don't want two neighbors item have the same colour.
2. The width of background colour have to set as the wisth of the parent container, not only the width of the TreeViewItem. The same for the CurrentSelection colour.
   This is my current xaml:

   ```
   <TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGenerationStep}"  AlternationCount="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
       <TreeView.ContextMenu>
           <ContextMenu>
               <MenuItem Header="Insert Step">
                   <MenuItem.Icon>
                       <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/add-icon.png" />
                   </MenuItem.Icon>
                   <MenuItem Header="Before" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_InsertBefore()]">
                       <MenuItem.Icon>
                           <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/blue-document-hf-insert-icon.png"  />
                       </MenuItem.Icon>
                   </MenuItem>
                   <MenuItem Header="After" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_InsertAfter()]">
                       <MenuItem.Icon>
                           <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/blue-document-hf-insert-footer-icon.png"  />
                       </MenuItem.Icon>
                   </MenuItem>
               </MenuItem>
               <MenuItem Header="Move">
                   <MenuItem.Icon>
                       <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/transform-move-icon.png" />
                   </MenuItem.Icon>
                   <MenuItem Header="Up" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_MoveUp()]">
                       <MenuItem.Icon>
                           <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/arrow-up-icon.png" />
                       </MenuItem.Icon>
                   </MenuItem>
                   <MenuItem Header="Down" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_MoveDown()]">
                       <MenuItem.Icon>
                           <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/arrow-down-icon.png" />
                       </MenuItem.Icon>
                   </MenuItem>
               </MenuItem>
               <MenuItem Header="Remove" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_Remove()]" >
                   <MenuItem.Icon>
                       <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/delete-icon.png" />
                   </MenuItem.Icon>
               </MenuItem>
               <MenuItem Header="Test" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_Test()]" >
               </MenuItem>
           </ContextMenu>
       </TreeView.ContextMenu>
       <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" >
               <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
               <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
               <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                   </Trigger>
                       <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#26EC3D12"></Setter>
                       </Trigger>
                       <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000"></Setter>
                       </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubSteps}" >
               <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Command}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="38"/>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   </TreeView>
   ```

Now i have two alternative colour, but the width is not relate to parent, but only to the TreeViewItem. I try HorizontalAlignment Strech, but don't work.
Any hint?

**EDIT 1**:

After some research, i found an article says the problem is the Default Templete Container of the TreeView. So i change with this code:

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow" Figures="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z"/>

    <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" >
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Width="16" Height="16" Background="Transparent" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#FF989898" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}">
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX="3" CenterY="3"/>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="3" CenterY="3"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF595959"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF262626"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"  Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding NeedHoming}" Content="need Homing" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGenerationStep}"  AlternationCount="2" >
        <TreeView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Insert Step">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/add-icon.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                    <MenuItem Header="Before" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_InsertBefore()]">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/blue-document-hf-insert-icon.png"  />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="After" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_InsertAfter()]">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/blue-document-hf-insert-footer-icon.png"  />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Move">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/transform-move-icon.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                    <MenuItem Header="Up" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_MoveUp()]">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/arrow-up-icon.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Down" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_MoveDown()]">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/arrow-down-icon.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Remove" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_Remove()]" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/MWPOS;component/Resource/icons/delete-icon.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Test" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_Test()]" >
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle1}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFEC3D12"/>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19747474"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubSteps}" >
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Command}"  Height="38"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

This create an alternate row, the problem is the background colour start after the TreeArrow, i prefer starting before, but its not a problem for now. With this style the Selection Colour is like the alternative colour, so its ok.
The problem is the alternative row count with nasted tree, sometimes have wrong colour, and i don't understand why. I think there's a wrong index about number of the row.

**EDIT 2:**
I found the problem, the AlternationCount restart from the child, now i trying found a solution to this problem...

**EDIT 3:**
Ok, the only method for change the Background is to add a BackGround Property to the TreeViewItem and call a function that calculate the Background for every TreeItem showed.

So the solution are change the default templete and add a "manual" check for the Background of the TreeViewItem

Comment: A quick comment would be .. have you tried to set width *, I haven't gone through all your code, but * is usually answer to such queries

Comment: Yes, the problem is related to Default Templete of TreeView. I add the edit, but i've the problem with alternative row colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is to change the default Template of the TreeView and add a property to set the Background color for every TreeViewItem.